# Http Status code for client needs to send back the request with additional information

Tags: rest, api, http-status-codes

Am a newbie to REST framework Http Status Codes. 
Creating an API which accepts a request from the client and sends the response back with the information they need to include in the request.

Example:

1. If a client sends the invalid account number or account number with conflict.API will return a message that account number is invalid or some message describing the error in the request. I cant send it as 201 or 200 since it's not a success also it can't be a 400 (not bad data since it's a valid one)

What is the Status code I should use for this scenario?

2. The user sends a valid data even though due to some case user needs to acknowledge the request he sent. API will return a message with validation detail and he needs to send back the request with the validation message

In this case, I can send 200 or 201 for the second request with validation details.. What should I return for the first request?

Answer (score 1):

If the request will never work as sent then 400 is the correct response.  A 400 does not mean that an individual item in the request is invalid, it means the request as a whole is invalid.  So if fields are missing then 400 is the correct response.

Comment: Also, if the account # is invalid in the sense that "the account number is a syntactically correct account number but no account with that number exists" then often a 404 is used since the request may technically be valid at some point in the future.

Comment: Thanks Pace for your prompt response. Let me tell you another scenario where I need to send the response with the validation message which client needs to approve and send back the request again... In this case, I cant send 400 or 404 since its a complete valid data.

Comment: In that case you might use 409 (Conflict) which loosely states "The request is valid but can't be processed in the state the server is currently in".

Comment: 409 Conflict can be used "where the user might be able to resolve the conflict and resubmit the request.  The server SHOULD generate a payload that includes enough information for a user to recognize the source of the conflict." https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.8

Answer (score 0):

This is up to you what you will choose according to the condition but I am sharing list of Standard HTTP Status Code here so you can check the below link and choose  Code according to the condition

https://github.com/prettymuchbryce/node-http-status

For your current scenario 400 will be a suitable :)